Need custom implementation for OAuth 2.0 Token Exchange grant type
I am having an SPA web application, say ABC where authentication is done using three different applications, say App1, App2 and App3. So what I do is when user tries to login to ABC, the user is given option to either Login via App1, App2 or App3. The user is redirected to either App1, App2 or App3 in a separate browser window as per user selection and they login with their credentials for that specific app. The access token received on successful login from App1/App2/App3 is given back to ABC frontend through modal window passing and this token will be exchanged to the authentication service of ABC where this token is validated and new access token for ABC with its claims is returned. I am making use of the token exchange grant type in OAuth 2.0 (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8693).
I was trying to use Duende IdentityServer which supports token exchange but I don't require the full capabilities of Duende Identity server. Since its licensed, I am planning to use a custom implementation of the token exchange grant type in my ABC application. How to achieve this custom implementation better and securely? I am using a .NET Core 8 backend Web API and Angular in frontend.
